# Session values in PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I just receive a old php site from a shared hosting service, that i need to migrate to a new data center. I came across this:

index.php has a login form, that submits login credentials to a login.php page

the form:

```
<form id="conct" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="login.php">
<input type="text" class="input" name="login" size="15">
<input type="password" class="input" name="pass" size="15">
```

the login:

```
session_start ();
header("Cache-control: private");

$_SESSION['login_control']=2;

if(@$login!="" && @$pass!="")
```

standard stuff, except that `$login` and `$pass` are empty, since the way of accessing request values in php is `$_SESSION["login"]` and `$_SESSION["pass"]`. This is working in the old production environment but I cannot put this to work in the new environment (without changing the code). Any idea how the values are passed?

I split this into two questions
the second can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125291/how-to-resize-images-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to your first questions: the register_globals on your old hosting will be enabled, while your new hosting correctly put that value to false.

For the second one: no idea.

Comment: thank you it solve my question and probably my job ;) I put the other part into a separated question.